# Nexus 4 reporting wrong xdpi

Tags: android, nexus-4

I'm calculating the screen width (in inches) like this:

```
DisplayMetrics dm = new DisplayMetrics();
activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(dm);
float wInches = dm.widthPixels / dm.xdpi;
```

This usually works fine. However, I noticed that on Nexus 4 (Android 4.4.4) **xdpi==159.895**

I saw in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20631221/why-lint-shows-warning-when-using-in-inch-or-mm-millimeter-units-as-dimensio/22707894#22707894) that he mentions other devices that return wrong values, but in his table Nexus 4 returns the right measure.

- Did anyone else notice this behavior?
- Is there a safe and accurate way of calculating the exact screen size?

Comment: I have same thing. Do you use cyanogen mod?

Comment: I don't know which ROM. Probably the original, but can't be sure.

Comment: Original gives correct values. I have cyanogenmod 4.4.4 and it gives wrong ones